# Is it safe to have a RFID card in the back of a Cellphone case

Tags: rfid

I hope this is the right Stack Exchange to ask this, but since RFID Cards are becoming more common and with new Microcontrollers a lot of home-built Internet of things devices can be RFID i figured here seemed right, if not i am truly sorry and will find somewhere else to ask.

I am wondering if it is safe to keep a RFID card in the back of a cellphone case (pressed right against the phones back) and to keep it in the case while using both the phone and the card.

Basically i keep my IPhone 6S in a drop-case and want to put my doors RFID proximity card in the back of the case so i don't have to carry an additional card when my phone is typically in my hand.

But i don't want to waste the money on the RFID card replacement, and more impotently i don't want to damage the 600+ IPhone.

Any help would be appreciated, little tid-bits i found around seems to indicate it would be okay, but i haven't found anything definitive.

Thanks in advance, Lin.

Comment: This question off topic for this forum. I think this one is more suitable for [EE.SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com). Having said that I still answered what I know best about RFID and cellular phone interfering.

Comment: Okay, i will ask again over there to be sure, sorry for being off topic, and thank you very much for your answer, it is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RFID card does not emit any electromagnetic signals when it is not close to a reader, it is designed to be passive. It is activated when brought in proximity to the reader. So RFID card cannot really damage your phone while it is in back case of you phone.

Comment: You contradict yourself, RFID do emit electromagnetic signals. But anyway I agree with the final conclusion- no harm will happen

Comment: @Rsf,  Thanks for pointing. I edited my response to clarify.

Comment: You might not want to store NFC cards there, though, if you 'phone has an NFC reader :-)